# How can i get group parameter in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

```
URL: abc.example.com/page/first/second
```

I need 'abc','first' and 'second' values in my controller.

## route.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.example.com'], function ()
{
        Route::get('page/{param1}/{param2}', MyController@index);
});
```

## MyCotroller.php

```
public function index($a,$b)
 {
    echo "Param1=".$a;
    echo "Param2=".$b; 
}
```

How can i get subdomain name in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
 public function index($sub,$a,$b)
{
  echo "Param1=".$a;
  echo "Param2=".$b; 
  echo "Sub =".$sub;
}
```

Remember first variable will be from group .

Better then this , use request

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
  echo "Param1=".$request->param1;
  echo "Param2=".$request->param2; 
  echo "Sub =".$request->sub;
}
```

Comment: It would be `param1` and `param2` instead of `a` and `b`